# Running Time of Algorithm to Generate Hadamard Matrix

Tags: algorithm, performance, matrix

I am trying to design an algorithm to generate a Hadamard matrix using a divide and conquer technique. To do so I decided to use four recursive calls to generate each term of the matrix and then continue with the recursive calls at each step for the Hadamard matrix of one value less. For example, H(3) is divided into 4 H(2) terms, with one being negative, and so forth until H(0). When working out the recurrence relation I ended up with

```
C(n) = 4C(n-1) + 1.
```

However, should divide and conquer involve division of the input instead of decreasing by 1? Conceptually though, I would think dividing a matrix into subsets of smaller matrices would qualify as divide and conquer. Anyways, I ended up with a running time of 4^n. Is this accurate for the algorithm I designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's accurate. Given the interpretation of `n`, the final matrix is `2^n`-by-`2^n`, with `4^n` elements. A recurrence involving `m`, the number of elements, would be

```
T(m) = 4T(m/4) + 1,
```

with a solution that is `O(m)`.

Comment: Thanks! So by the Master Theorem the running time of the algorithm I designed would be n rather than 4^n?

Comment: @CS-DS-ES-FS Again, either is correct depending on how you define n. Your algorithm is asymptotically optimal.